# RecyclerView - how to stack items instead of scroll off screen?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I noticed a cool effect in a game I've been playing and was wondering how to accomplish it in an android application using the RecyclerView (or any other kind of list object in android).

What I'm trying to accomplish: when you scroll the items in the recyclerview, instead of having those items scroll off the screen, I'd like those items to start stacking on top of each other near the edge of the screen. So when you scroll towards the edge, the items start stacking on top of each other. And when you scroll away from the edge towards the middle of the screen, the items start unstacking off of each other.

I'd post an image, but I currently don't have enough reputation, so here is a link to what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://i66.tinypic.com/1z3uubm.gif

Another link in case other one is not available:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEhOe.jpg

Any code examples or a general direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.